# I need a timer to temporarily disable mouseover event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm looking for a simple way to temporarily disable a mouseover event, for literally 1000 miliseconds. All my attempts to do so, have so-far failed.  I am trying to stop my images from flickering when the mouse enters several times as it hovers over the edge of the div. Here is my code:

```js
var ranNum, result_10, resultFloor, piccy, audio;

function myFunction() {
    ranNum = Math.random();
    result_10 = (ranNum * 5) + 1;
    resultFloor = Math.floor(result_10);
    piccy = "<img src=\"random_images/" + resultFloor + ".gif\" />";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = piccy;
    audio = document.getElementById("audio");
       audio.play();
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="demo" onmouseenter="myFunction()">This</div>
    <audio id="audio" src="pop.wav" ></audio>
</div>
```

Comment: seems like you need a debounce function.  i typically use the debounce in lodash but there are probably lots of plain js examples out there if you're going that route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will stop the flicker:

```js
var ranNum, result_10, resultFloor, piccy, audio;
var isPlaying = false;

var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
function myFunction() {
  if (!isPlaying) {
 isPlaying = true;
 ranNum = Math.random();
 result_10 = (ranNum * 5) + 1;
 resultFloor = Math.floor(result_10);
 piccy = "<img src=\"http://d2.alternativeto.net/dist/icons/cloudapp_2094.png?width=64&height=64&mode=crop&upscale=false\" />";
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = piccy;
    // check every 1/2 second to see if the audio has ended
 var t = setInterval(function() {
     console.log(audio.ended);
    if (audio.ended) {
       isPlaying = false;
       clearInterval(t);
    }
 }, 500);
 audio.play();
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div id="demo" onmouseenter="myFunction()">This</div>
    <audio id="audio" src="http://freewavesamples.com/files/Casio-MT-45-Pops.wav" ></audio>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty approach. Simply uses a variable referencing a function, and changes the reference to point to a function that does nothing, then back to the original function.

I agree with Kosch's suggestion of using the underscore/lodash debounce function if you're already using those libraries or if you see them helping you in more than just this one case.

```js
var ranNum, result_10, resultFloor, piccy, audio;

function myFunction() {
        disableMouseOverHandler();
  ranNum = Math.random();
 result_10 = (ranNum * 5) + 1;
 resultFloor = Math.floor(result_10);
 piccy = "<img src=\"random_images/" + resultFloor + ".gif\" />";
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = piccy;
 audio = document.getElementById("audio");
       audio.play();

}

function doNothing() {
}

var mouseOverHandler = myFunction;

function disableMouseOverHandler() {
  mouseOverHandler = doNothing;
  setTimeout(function(){ mouseOverHandler = myFunction; }, 3000);
  //I used 3000ms (3 seconds) to make it more pronounced.
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div id="demo" onmouseenter="mouseOverHandler()">This</div>
    <audio id="audio" src="pop.wav" ></audio>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you. EDIT: Although, I just tried in chrome and it didn't work, only IE.

Comment: That's odd. I'm testing in chrome and seeing it work fine. Is it this embedded snippet that's giving you trouble?

Comment: I'm not sure, here's a live version, see what you think: http://infinitedv.co.uk/rantest/random_test_2.html  I haven't preloaded the images, so it may take a few tries to load all the images.

Comment: In your case you want to move the disableMouseOverHandler call into the "myFunction". I'll update the example.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myFunctionDisabled = null;

function disableMyFunction() {
  clearTimeout(myFunctionDisabled);
  myFunctionDisabled = setTimeout(function() { myFunctionDisabled = false; }, 1000);
}

function myFunction() {
  if (myFunctionDisabled) return;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, very elegant solution. :)